# Vector identity used in electromagnetism

Tags: vector-fields, electromagnetism

Is there a simple proof of this identity or a reference to some textbook where could I find a simple proof of the $(1)$?

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times (\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E})=-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{B})\tag{1}$$
where Maxwell’s version of Faraday’s law of induction is

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deriving the equation

$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times (\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E})=-\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{B})\tag{1}$

from

$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \mathbf E = -\dfrac{\partial{\mathbf B}}{\partial t}  \tag 2$

is really more a matter of muliple variable calculus than electromagnetism.  We are merely using the fact that, for sufficiently differentiable $\mathbf B$ (I'm pretty sure $C^2$ will do), the order in which we take partial derivatives is immaterial to the result.  Therefore, taking $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times$ of each side of (2) to obtain

$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \mathbf E) = -\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \dfrac{\partial{\boldsymbol B}}{\partial t}, \tag 3$

we need simply interchange the order of the derivatives occurring on the right-hand side (that is, of $\partial / \partial t$ and $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times$) and ***voila!*** (1) is obtained.

Comment: Thank you very much for yor explanation. It is just an inversion of $\partial$ and $\nabla$. You made me smile when you wrote: voila! For me it's a beautiful welcome you gave me.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  you are more than welcome my friend, and thanks for the "acceptance"!  By the way, have you checked out vol. II of ***The Feynman Lectures on Physics***?  It is a beautiful introductory study of E&M!  Cheers!

Comment: You are 100% authorized to modify my tags. :-) I was already a member of this community two years ago, but I escaped because there are many evil people. With all the sincerity of this world I have seen the users and I think they have gone away. Thank you very much for your welcome. You will also be welcome for me on TeX.SE where there are the same friends who attend this community.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  thanks again for your kind words!